# How can I update the phone numbers of contacts in Android Studios

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-contacts

I am new to developing apps with android studio, and I decided to make an app to edit the phone numbers of my phone contacts as my first test app.

I use a class to get information about all the contacts that I have on my cell phone, then I have created a listview where I show the contact's name, ID, avatar and registered phone numbers.

The information has been gotten from the ContactsContract.Contacts table. This all works fine, so far.

But now I have to edit the phone numbers of all the contacts, but I don't know exactly how to do it. I've been going through the Android devs documentation but I can't get anything that can help me. I don't want to use Intent in this case.

I have this kotlin class that I use to get the information of all contacts is this:

```
@file:Suppress("unused")
    package com.example.uimx
    import android.Manifest
    import android.content.ContentUris
    import android.content.Context
    import android.net.Uri
    import android.provider.ContactsContract
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresPermission

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    fun Context.isContactExists(
            phoneNumber: String
    ): Boolean {
        val lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(phoneNumber)
        )
        val projection = arrayOf(
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID,
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME
        )
        contentResolver.query(lookupUri, projection, null, null, null).use {
            return (it?.moveToFirst() == true)
        }
    }

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    @JvmOverloads
    fun Context.retrieveAllContacts(
            searchPattern: String = "",
            retrieveAvatar: Boolean = true,
            limit: Int = -1,
            offset: Int = -1
    ): List<ContactData> {
        val result: MutableList<ContactData> = mutableListOf()
        contentResolver.query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                CONTACT_PROJECTION,
                if (searchPattern.isNotBlank()) "${ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY} LIKE '%?%'" else null,
                if (searchPattern.isNotBlank()) arrayOf(searchPattern) else null,
                if (limit > 0 && offset > -1) "${ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY} ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset"
                else ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC"
        )?.use {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val contactId = it.getLong(it.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PROJECTION[0]))
                    val name = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PROJECTION[2])) ?: ""
                    val hasPhoneNumber = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PROJECTION[3])).toInt()
                    val phoneNumber: List<String> = if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                        retrievePhoneNumber(contactId)
                    } else mutableListOf()

                    val avatar = if (retrieveAvatar) retrieveAvatar(contactId) else null
                    result.add(ContactData(contactId, name, phoneNumber, avatar))
                } while (it.moveToNext())
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    private fun Context.retrievePhoneNumber(contactId: Long): List<String> {
        val result: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        contentResolver.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                "${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID} =?",
                arrayOf(contactId.toString()),
                null
        )?.use {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    result.add(it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)))
                } while (it.moveToNext())
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    private fun Context.retrieveAvatar(contactId: Long): Uri? {
        return contentResolver.query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                "${ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID} =? AND ${ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE} = '${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}'",
                arrayOf(contactId.toString()),
                null
        )?.use {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                val contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        contactId
                )
                Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        contactUri,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY
                )
            } else null
        }
    }

    private val CONTACT_PROJECTION = arrayOf(
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
    )

    data class ContactData(
            val contactId: Long,
            val name: String,
            val phoneNumber: List<String>,
            val avatar: Uri?
    )
```

I have a button prepared that receives the click event and calls a function that would have the script to replace all the phone numbers of all the contacts, for new phone numbers that I will define for each contact.

I have this next code that I got on the internet but I can't get it to work in my app.

```
private int  updateContactPhoneByID(long rawContactId)
{
    int ret = 0;

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    // Update data table phone number use contact raw contact id.
    if(rawContactId > -1) {
        // Update mobile phone number.
        updatePhoneNumber(contentResolver, rawContactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE, "66666666666666");

        // Update work mobile phone number.
        updatePhoneNumber(contentResolver, rawContactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE, "8888888888888888");

        // Update home phone number.
        updatePhoneNumber(contentResolver, rawContactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME, "99999999999999999");

        ret = 1;
    }else
    {
        ret = 0;
    }

    return ret;
}

/* Update phone number with raw contact id and phone type.*/
private void updatePhoneNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver, long rawContactId, int phoneType, String newPhoneNumber)
{
    // Create content values object.
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    // Put new phone number value.
    contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newPhoneNumber);

    // Create query condition, query with the raw contact id.
    StringBuffer whereClauseBuf = new StringBuffer();

    // Specify the update contact id.
    whereClauseBuf.append(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID);
    whereClauseBuf.append("=");
    whereClauseBuf.append(rawContactId);

    // Specify the row data mimetype to phone mimetype( vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2 )
    whereClauseBuf.append(" and ");
    whereClauseBuf.append(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE);
    whereClauseBuf.append(" = '");
    String mimetype = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    whereClauseBuf.append(mimetype);
    whereClauseBuf.append("'");

    // Specify phone type.
    whereClauseBuf.append(" and ");
    whereClauseBuf.append(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
    whereClauseBuf.append(" = ");
    whereClauseBuf.append(phoneType);

    // Update phone info through Data uri.Otherwise it may throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.
    Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    // Get update data count.
    int updateCount = contentResolver.update(dataUri, contentValues, whereClauseBuf.toString(), null);
}
```

How to make the above script work to update the correct contact table with the information I have.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a confusion about contactId and rawContactId.

When you read all the contacts from the device, you're getting the `contactId` of that contact, but the `updateContactPhoneByID` method you're trying to use is expecting a `rawContactId` which is different.

In a nutshell, every `Contact` in the `ContactsContract.Contacts` table is comprised out of multiple `RawContacts` each is usually synced by some different app or account (e.g. one RawContact from your personal Google account, another RawContact from your work Google account, another one from Whatsapp, and one from Yahoo), the details from ALL these `RawContacts` are join to make up a single contact profile.

I'm not sure how you want the edit to work, if a contact has multiple phone numbers, do you want to replace ALL those phones with a single new phone number, or do you allow the user to type multiple phones in your edit screen?

Anyway, here's a small kotlin function that takes a contactId and an existing phone number X and replaces that single number with a new one.
I hope you can adapt it to your needs.

```
private fun updatePhone(contactId:Long, existingNumber:String, newNumber:String) {
  val contentValues = ContentValues()
  contentValues.put(Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)

  val where = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?" + " AND " + Phone.NUMBER + "=?"
  val whereArgs = arrayOf<String>((contactId).toString(), Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, existingNumber)

  contentResolver.update(Data.CONTENT_URI, contentValues, where, whereArgs)
}
```

Note that the `existingNumber` param must match the string in the ContactsContract DB exactly.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. 
What I want to do is replace ALL phone numbers (mobile phone, work phone, home phone, etc...) of each contact with new phone numbers (I generate those new numbers randomly with another function that works well.). I'm gonna test your function to check if this works for me.