# How can I edit the phone number of a contact in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts

I have got a contact data class with the unique contact ID and want to change the phone number of the contact.
Here's the data class:

```
data class Contact(
        val id : String,
        val name : String,
        val number : String)
```

I have found a tutorial on how to do this with an intent, however I would like to do this using the contactsProvider in Android. I already have WRITE_CONTACT permissions declared in the manifest, but still don't know on how to save the phone number to an existing contact. I'm also unable to find any good tutrial on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet of code that will update a current phone number to a new phone number for a given contact ID:

```
private fun updatePhone(contactId:Long, existingNumber:String, newNumber:String) {
  val contentValues = ContentValues()
  contentValues.put(Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)

  val where = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?" + " AND " + Phone.NUMBER + "=?"
  val whereArgs = arrayOf<String>((contactId).toString(), Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, existingNumber)

  contentResolver.update(Data.CONTENT_URI, contentValues, where, whereArgs)
}
```

Here's some more explanation behind this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63761333/819355

*I would have marked this question as a duplicate of the linked question, but the linked question doesn't have any accepted answer so it won't let me.*